# Wrapper operation trouble

Tags: c

I am having a terrible time understanding how to get the wrapper to work with these encryption programs. I got a Caesar cipher program to work to both encrypt and decrypt, now I am working on a Vigenere cipher. I have the program working but when I use a key that will cause the letters to wrap around I get odd results. Here is the code I am using:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char s2[25];
    strcpy(s2, argv[1]);
    printf("Please enter a string of text to be encrypted!\n");
    string p = GetString();
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(p); i < n; i++)
    {
        if (isupper(p[i])){

        char c = (p[i] - 'A' + s2[i]);
        printf("%c", c);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

}
```

This code will work if the command line input is `./program BACON` and I enter BLAH for the text to be encrypted. If for example I use `./program ZZZZZ` as the key then I will get all kinds of odd results because it does not wrap back around. I have tried using the modulus operator and have left it out of the code I just posted because I still could not get it to wrap with that. I am just starting to learn programming.

### Update

Maybe you can help me understand the math better; your code works perfectly, but I have been trying to figure this out on a calculator manually just to see what's going on. This is what I have so far:

```
./program HHHHH
```

keyLen should equal 5 in my understanding and so if I give p[i] a value of "H"

```
keyLen= 5
p[i]= H   //or 72 in ASCII 
int sum = (p[i] - 'A') + (s2[i % keyLen] - 'A'); //sum = (72 - '65') + ([72 % 5] - '65');
char c = 'A' + sum%26; // c = 65 + -11
```

Maybe my math is way off because when I do things in the order I think they should be done sum = negative 63 and so a 26 mod of -63 which gives me negative 11. Which clearly is not right because that equals 54 when you add 65 and negative 11.

Even if I make the negative 11 a positive integer of 11 and add 65 I get 76 which is ASCII character "L" but the right answer is "O". I am clearly doing something wrong but I've been working on the solution for a while now and keep coming up with the same results.

Comment: What did you find out when you debugged your code?

Comment: What is `s2[i]` going to be if (for example) s2 is 5 characters long, and `i` is 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two "wrap-around" issues in your program:

- Your letters do not wrap around when the key and the current letter combine to produce a value beyond 26, and
- You read past the end of the key when the length of the word being encrypted exceeds the length of the key.

Here is how you fix it: right after copying the key into `s2`, do this:

```
int keyLen = strlen(s2);
```

Now inside your loop do this:

```
int sum = (p[i] - 'A') + (s2[i % keyLen] - 'A'); // Calculate the sum of key+word
char c = 'A' + sum%26; // Wrap around at 26, the number of letters in the alphabet
```

This will make the output look "normal".

Once you figure out how the last formula works, you should be able to modify it to decode the word.